# How to consume odata service ABAP in android studio?

Tags: android, odata, abap, netweaver

I need to login to SAP Netweaver gateway from android mobile application by using odata service in sap abap . without using SMP

Answer (score 1):

The SAP Gateway Productivity Accelerator is not supported any more.
You should use instead the new SAP Cloud Platform SDK for Android.
https://blogs.sap.com/2018/06/06/sap-cloud-platform-sdk-for-android-has-arrived/

Answer (score 0):

SAP provides a Gateway Productivity Accelerator that includes toolkits for the most common tech. ecosystems from where you would want to consume a SAP Gateway OData service(including Android). This is installable in Eclipse via Hana OnDemand repositories.
For more details [check this](https://blogs.sap.com/2013/06/11/how-to-create-android-application-consuming-odata-service-with-help-of-gateway-productivity-accelerator-gwpa/).

Cheers,
Sepo